# Signed Route In Larave 9

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I have added signed route. and it is working perfectly. but the problem is, when I start the server and hit `127.0.0.1:8000` in the browser it shows `403 INVALID SIGNATURE`. when I give a route like this `127.0.0.1:8000/welcome` than it is working. please someone help me, so that this `127.0.0.1:8000` works with sign route.

i am using laravel 9

**My Route**
`Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\website\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('/')->middleware('signed');`

[scerrnshot of error](https://prnt.sc/w7lM0e0SoXwM)

[Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13ETivLzTiT5lLavXDpXs4y3dch5juhLx/view)

Comment: You can't access `127.0.0.1:8000/` (i.e. route `/`) without providing a valid signature. You specified this requirement yourself when requiring `/` to be signed. I don't understand what your issue is here. Are you actually providing a valid signature and it's not working?

Comment: @apokryfos i am providing a valid signature and working fine. but the issue is happing for the first time when i hit ```http://127.0.0.1:8000/``` in the browser. first time this shows 403. but when i brows other URL than it is working file.

Comment: @apokryfos i would like to request you to watch this 58 sec video.  
  video link -  https://drive.google.com/file/d/13ETivLzTiT5lLavXDpXs4y3dch5juhLx/view

Comment: I still don't understand what you want to do. When your route is signed you must always provide a valid signature. This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0):

Answer in your question. If do you want to use signed url for root page you must implement this with sign. You don't. If you define your route like this:

```
Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\website\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('/')->middleware('signed');
```

you should use sign for access this page.

For example imagine two routes

```
Route::get('/a', [HomeController::class,'index'])->name('homepage');
Route::get('/', [HomeController::class,'index'])->name('homepage2')->middleware('signed');
```

if in your index view you call signed homepage2 you don't get 403